# Recursion Stack Overflow Error Java

Tags: java, recursion

Stack Overflow Error in Recursion Method when trying to print the first m multiples of a positive integer n. How do I fix it? Code below is already logically correct:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Exercise3
  {
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n, m;
  System.out.println("Please enter values of n and m: ");
  n = keyboard.nextInt();
  m = keyboard.nextInt();
  // logic of code explained above
  for(int i = (m -(m - 1)); i <= m; i++)
  {
     System.out.print(multiple(n * i) + ",");
  }

  }
  // Now Write the Recursive method
  public static int multiple(int n)
  {
     if(n == 0)
        return 1;
      else 
       return multiple(n);
  }
```

}

Comment: Your recursive method has no exit condition.

Comment: Was about to say some thing as Juned. If all multiple does is call itself, then you will obviously have a stack overflow.

Comment: Your edit isn't much better. For all values going into multiple that are not zero, you'll still end up with an infinite recursion as the parameters to a recursion function should change upon each call, otherwise a stack overflow will always occur (assuming no external state).

Comment: Could you let us know what output you're trying to produce?  It looks like the `n * i` is producing the multiples for you, so that the `multiple` method doesn't accomplish anything useful.

Comment: can you put some sample that you want to achieve.?

Comment: n = 2, m = 5. Therefore, the first 5 multiples of 2 should be                        2, 4, 6, 8, 10

Comment: If you remove the recursive method and just print with the main method you will see the correct output. I just can't do it recursively tho.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very bad use of recursion

```
public static int multiple(int n){ // once come into this method will never exit
  return multiple(n); // again and again call multiple
}
```

There is no exit condition from this recursion method. You need to think about an exit condition to terminate this recursive call.

Edit: for your edit:

```
public static int multiple(int n) { // inside this method n is never change
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return multiple(n);// still no termination for the recursion call      
}
```

Comment: @gexcen still your recursion has no exit. check my edit

Answer (score 3):

you probably want to do this:

```
for(int i = (m -(m - 1)); i <= m; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(multiple(n,i)+",");  // call like this in you main method
    }
```

This is recursive function :

```
 public static int multiple(int m,int n) {

        if (n == 1)
            return m;
        else
            return  m+multiple(m,n-1);


    }
```

Comment: Please, do not use a variable and and a pre/post-increment or decrement of a variable in the same statement.  While Java is defined so that this has a definite result, in C/C++ or other languages the result may depend on the compiler, because you don't know for sure whether the `n` to the left of `*` will be accessed before or after it is decremented.  This matters because people asking questions here are likely to use other languages at other points in their career.  It should be `n * multiple (n-1)` which is unambiguous.

Comment: Also, this method computes a factorial, but I don't think it's what the questioner wanted.  I haven't yet figured out what he wants, though.

Comment: I want to print lets say n is 2, and m is 5. Then I print the first 5 multiples of 2: 2, 4 ,6, 8, 10

Comment: @gexcen now check my answer. hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. Very smart how since it deals with multiples you simply add n because adding n is the same as getting the multiples of n. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
       import java.util.Scanner;
       public class Exercise3
       {
          public static void main (String args[])
          {
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
             int n, m;
            System.out.println("Please enter values of n and m: ");
            n = keyboard.nextInt();
            m = keyboard.nextInt();
            // logic of code explained above
            for(int i = (m -(m - 1)); i <= m; i++)
            {
            System.out.print(n * i + ",");
            }
           }    

              }
```

// Use n = 2 and m = 5 to see first 5 multiples of 2. I need a recursive method to do the same thing. This is iterative